# Windows, c++ detect finger touch on screen?

Tags: touch

In virtual key codes in c++ vk_shift means the shift key for example. But is there any such code to indicate that a finger is touching the touchscreen ? Or how is it handled ?

Comment: On C++? .NET? On a particular form or the global context?

Comment: Yes c++ sorry its not mentioned

Comment: Edit them to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches. Either use [Touch Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-messages) which will give you a very raw result in [TOUCHINPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-touchinput), x-y point of the touch events, mostly useful for debugging purpose or if your app needs a unique interface, or [Touch Gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-gestures-overview), which will be immediately familiar for users accustomed to other touch interfaces since you'll be handling [GESTUREINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-gestureinfo), where you'll get tap, zoom, pan and rotation instead.